# $X \sim N(0, \sigma_1^2)$, $Y \sim N(0, \sigma_2^2)$, $U = X+Y$. What are $E[X|U], E[Y|U]$?

Tags: probability, self-study

$X \sim N(0, \sigma_1^2)$, $Y \sim N(0, \sigma_2^2)$, $U = X+Y$.

What are the values of $E[X|U], E[Y|U]$?

I understand $E[X|U] + E[Y|U] = U$, but I'm not sure how to move forward...

Comment: Are you assuming independence?

Comment: @Chaconne yes. X, Y are independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X$ and $U = X+Y$ are zero-mean *jointly normal* random variables with variances
$\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2$ and covariance 
$\operatorname{cov}(X,U) = E[XU]=E[X(X+Y)]=E[X^2]=\sigma_1^2$.

For jointly normal random variables $X$ and $U$,
it is well-known that
the *linear* minimum-mean-square-error estimator of $X$ given $U$, *viz.,*
$$\hat{X} = \frac{\operatorname{cov}(X,U)}{\operatorname{var}(U)}U
= \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}U$$
is the same as the *unconstrained* minimum-mean-square-error estimator
$E[X\mid U]$, giving us
$$E[X\mid U] = \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}U$$
with a minimum of fuss or tedious algebra.

Answer (score 2):

There well could be a better way but this gets the job done.

From Bayes rule we have
$$
f(x|u) = \frac{f(u|x) f(x)}{f(u)}.
$$

$X \sim N(0, \sigma_X^2)$ and $Y \sim N(0, \sigma_Y^2)$. $X \perp Y \implies U \sim N(0, \sigma_U^2 := \sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2)$. Furthermore $U|X = Y+x|X=x \sim N(x, \sigma^2_Y)$ so we have that
$$
f(x|u) = \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2_Y}} \exp{(-\frac{(u-x)^2}{2\sigma_Y^2})} \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2_X}} \exp{(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma_X^2})}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2_U}} \exp{(-\frac{u^2}{2\sigma_U^2})}}
$$

After a lot of tedious algebra, completing the square, and using $\sigma^2_U = \sigma^2_X + \sigma^2_Y$ to cancel a lot of stuff, we find that
$$
X|U \sim N(\frac{u\sigma^2_X}{\sigma^2_X + \sigma^2_Y}, \frac{\sigma^2_X\sigma^2_Y}{\sigma^2_X + \sigma^2_Y}).
$$

This gives us $E(X|U)$ and then we can use the property that you mentioned that $E(X|U) + E(Y|U) = u$ to get $E(Y|U)$.